# 18:04: WiFi OK but ethernet LAN connection fails

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

i just installed ubuntu 18.04 lts on a lap top but hav no lan but i do have wireless any ideas on that
 sudo lshw -c network results

```
network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: WiFi Link 5100
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
   logical name: wlp14s0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:16:ea:75:d3:8e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-74-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.1.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:25 memory:f2100000-f2101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:14:00.0
       logical name: enp20s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1e:ec:5b:ee:30
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f2010000-f2010fff memory:f2000000-f200ffff memory:80600000-8060ffff
```

Comment: Everything looks good here. Can you elaborate on "no lan". Where are you connecting it?

Comment: The problem is solved by plugging to another port.

Comment: @Pilot6 please re-read the edited **Update #1** in my answer. The WAN/LAN port problem only occurred **after** OP attempted their own troubleshooting, by rewiring ethernet cables, and didn't reconnect them properly when they were done.

Comment: Status please... is your ethernet working now?

Answer (score 1):

The r8169 driver that runs your ethernet interface is known to be buggy, and lately it's been really buggy.

In `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software databases

`sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` # replace the r8169 driver with r8168 driver

`reboot` # reboot the system

**Update #1:**

Initially wireless access was working, which meant that the router was properly connected to the cable modem. While troubleshooting this problem, they re-cabled the ethernet wires, but after resetting the cables to original configuration, later found that the ethernet cable was incorrectly plugged into the WAN port on the rear of the router. Re-plugged it into the correct LAN port, reconnected the WAN port to the cable modem, and it's all working now. **The r8168 driver fixed the original problem.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103904/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-1804-wifi-ok-but-ethernet-lan-connection-fail).

Comment: that's not how flags work NOR is that how the system was designed for comments.  All your comments have been moved to chat, OP and yourself have chat access in that room.  If you have problems with this, then **don't have huge comment thread discussions** because this isn't what comments are supposed to be for (and is WHY chat exists for extended discussions)